# PHP: Can't get month at the right year

Tags: php, forms, date, select, cakephp-2.x

For the code below i want to have the current month and the next 12 months with the year. Im using a loop for it, everyting works fine except for "January". And i just don't know whats going wrong.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $months[ucfirst(strftime("%B %G", strtotime( date( 'Y-m' )." +$i months")))] = ucfirst(strftime("%B %G", strtotime( date( 'Y-m' )." +$i months")));
    echo ucfirst(strftime("%B %G", strtotime( date( 'Y-m' )." +$i months")));
}
```

The echo output:

```
December 2015 Januari 2015 Februari 2016 Maart 2016 April 2016 Mei 2016 Juni 2016 Juli 2016 Augustus 2016 September 2016 Oktober 2016 November 2016 December 2016
```

Comment: Try using `date('M-y')` rather than `('Y-m')`

Comment: Tip: don't abuse strings when doing calculations of any kind (including time).

Comment: @Fredrik thanks, its has worked. But why was mine wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
$date = new DateTime('first day of this month');

for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
    echo $date->format('F Y,');
    $date->modify('+1 month');
}
```

The output would be:

> December 2015, January 2016, February 2016, March 2016, April 2016, May 2016, June 2016, July 2016, August 2016, September 2016, October 2016, November 2016, December 2016,

Comment: Im sorry but a needed it in Dutch and in a var for select (in a form). The solution from Frederik Worked fine.

Comment: If the current date is towards the end of the month, you can have problems with skipping months. For example, setting `$date = new DateTime('2015-12-31')'` will skip February. You need to make sure it's the start of the month.

Comment: I've just verified and you're right.. I've just updated my answer. Thanks. Your answer is pretty good as well :)

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this?

```
<?php

$start = new DateTimeImmutable('first day of this month');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, 12);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('F Y') . PHP_EOL;
}
```